# Как записать в массив строки из файла в цикле?

Tags: delphi, строки, файлы

Как передать в массив чтение строк с 1 по 5 ? Потому что копирование кода, как то не впечатляет:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  F: TextFile;
  S1: string;
  S2: Array[0..5] of String;
  i: Integer;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    AssignFile(F, OpenDialog1.FileName);
    Reset(F);
    Readln(F, S1);
    S2[0] := S1;
    Readln(F, S1);
    S2[1] := S1;
    Readln(F, S1);
    S2[2] := S1;
    Readln(F, S1);
    S2[3] := S1;
    Readln(F, S1);
    S2[4] := S1;
    Readln(F, S1);
    S2[5] := S1;
    CloseFile(F);
  end;

  for i:=0 to 5 do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(S2[i]);
end;
```

Comment: [Не нужно включать язык в заголовок вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3480/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0). Особенно в том виде, как это постоянно делаете вы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if OpenDialog1.Execute then
begin
   AssignFile(F, OpenDialog1.FileName);
   Reset(F);
   for i:=0 to 5 do
   begin
     Readln(F, S1);
     S2[i] := S1;
   end;
   CloseFile(F);
end;

for i:=0 to 5 do
   Memo1.Lines.Add(S2[i]);
```

Comment: `s2[]` то рудимент какой-то

Comment: @Igor, А в данном коде: реально увеличить длину массива до 5млн., то есть Array[0..5000000] of String; Максимально что мне позволяет программа это 150000 а дальше выкидывает из программы. Спрашиваю ради интереса?

Comment: Нет, не реально. Это потребует 20 МБ свободного места в стеке. Что значит "позволяет программа"?

Comment: @Igor, Ну к примеру - когда извлекаю из большого файла 150000 строк то все нормально. А когда параметр устанавливаю на 5млн. То сразу выкидывает с программы с ошибкой. То есть по сути 150000 это потолок ?.

Comment: @Татьяна После всех Ваших вопросов про ошибки c "Out of memory" Вам пора уже научиться работать с огромными файлами, сделав для себя некоторые выводы о возможности/необходимости загрузки всего содержимого таких файлов в память.

Comment: @Igor, Это я для общего познания. Сейчас уже с огромными файлами я не работаю, но тем не менее - интересуюсь, периодически, этим вопросом. С Вами полностью согласна. А спросила потому что: в данном случае - программа и так быстро 150000 строк извлекает, за 2-3 секунды. Я просто, наивная и думала что можно, вот так просто, до 5 млн. увеличить, но судя по комментариям, нельзя...

Comment: @Татьяна на кой вам этот массив то нужен? Если уж очень хочется, то 5 млн вы при желании сможете загрузить не в массив а в `TStringList`, там память будет выделяться из кучи, а не в стеке. 
Другой вопрос в том, что мемо сдохнет вам это показать.

Comment: @teran Человек написал: "массив нужен для общего познания".

Answer (score 3):

```
for i := 0 to 5 do
begin
  Readln(F, S1);
  S2[i] := S1;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(S2[i]);
end;
```